# How to unzip a folder in linux?

Tags: linux, unzip

I have a file named backup.zip which multiple files and subdirectories. How could I extract directory 'CSS' into a folder called /var/www?

This is what i've tried, but it only works for files.

```
unzip backup.zip CSS -d /var/www/
```

Comment: Do you need to make it only from terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Did you try running `unzip` like this?

```
unzip backup.zip CSS/* -d /var/www/
```

(Note the asterisk after CSS)

There's a discussion related in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59276/how-to-extract-only-a-specific-folder-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory - looks like unix.stackexchange.com is a better place for this kind of questions.

Comment: I believe `CSS/*` would be more appropriate as your `CSS*` would also extract files from any directory named `CSS2` or something similar.

Comment: @Chirag64 - Yes, you are right.  I will edit the answer.  Thanks for the tip :)